# Javascript code to randomize the css file used

Tags: javascript, css, random, load

I have used this code in the past

```
function getRand(){
    return Math.round(Math.random()*(css.length-1));
}

var css = new Array(
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1.css">',
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/2.css">',
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/3.css">'
    );

rand = getRand();
document.write(css[rand]);
```

Now I have been told to place the function inside this event handler:

```
$(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", function(e, pid) {
        // insert function here
});
```

Could someone please explain what part of my code goes where? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean to place the function call in there, and not the actual function definition..

```
 function getRandCss(){
    var css = ['<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1.css">',
     '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/2.css">',
     '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/3.css">'];

    return  css[Math.round(Math.random()*(css.length-1))];
  }

$(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", function(e, pid){

  $('body').append( getRandCss() );

});
```

---

But if you indeed have to put everything inside it

```
$(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", function(e, pid){

  function getRandCss(){
    var css = ['<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1.css">',
     '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/2.css">',
     '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/3.css">'];

    return  css[Math.round(Math.random()*(css.length-1))];
  }

  $('body').append( getRandCss() );

});
```

Comment: Yes! Fantastic, so you have to append the function. This would work with most functions?

Comment: @uriah, we do not append the function.. We append the returned string **from** the function. the actual `<link rel=.... >`. If you wanted to include html that is displayed (a div an image or something similar) you would need to first identify where you want to insert it in the DOM and append it there.. The `link` element you append could also go in the `head` tag, so instead of `$('body').append` you could also do `$('head').append`

Answer (score 0):

The first function returns a random number, between 0 and the length of the array. That number will be used to access the array, which contains several link tags to load the different css.
In the last function, its binding it to the load complete event, so that it set the css when the page fully is loaded.
That's what is doing, personally, I don't think that's the best way to do it.